# xampp mod_rewrite not working in localhost VirtualHost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I have a VirtualHost local.mywebsite.com , I use Rewrite rules 
**in my .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|\'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=BadQueryString,F]

RewriteRule ^ - [E=BASE:{DOCBASE}] [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://local.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin/
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ %{ENV:BASE}$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9!-/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE} [L]
```

**in the httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "E:/websites/local.mywebsite.com"
   ServerName local.mywebsite.com
   <Directory "E:/websites/local.mywebsite.com">
    # AllowOverride All      # Deprecated
    # Order Allow,Deny       # Deprecated
    # Allow from all         # Deprecated
     AllowOverride All
    # --New way of doing it
    Require all granted    
</Directory>
```

**and in httpd.conf**

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

and i uncomment the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

but local.mywebsite.com/fr  return Error 404

Comment: have you uncommented `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in httpd.conf?

Comment: i'm in windows so i did it manually by editing the httpd file and i uncomment the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted apache after uncommenting rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so ?
If not so restart apache. If yes check If in your httpd.conf file httpd-vhosts.conf is included. if not so Dot it.

Make sur there is this folder "fr" in your project.

If it is not still working I recommand you put the project in your htdocs folder in xampp folder. There may be a right acces problem.

Comment: I don't need to add the fr folder because it is a (virtual folder) in  rewrite rule So my be like you said it is a right access issue

Comment: will unfortunately , putting the project in htdocs folder it doesn't work either :(